# How can I add Mobile Broadband API to my C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mobile-broadband-api

As the title says, what is the preferred way to add the Mobile Broadband API to my C# WPF application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps that worked for me. The file you're looking for is mbnapi.tlb which for me (I'm on Windows 8) is located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x64\mbnapi.tlb

There are a few different folders where you could find this file to work with OS versions (8.0, 8.1, ...) and processor architectures (x86, x64, ...).

Once you have located that file use the normal procedure to reference it in Visual Studio:

- Click the Project item in the toolbar, and then click Add Reference from the drop-down menu.
- From the Add Reference page, click the Browse tab.
- Browse to the Mbnapi.tlb file and select it. Then, click OK.

Reference: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/MB_ManagedCode.docx